# Can a contract own EOS which can be staked?

Tags: voting, staking

Can a contract own EOS, such that the contract has all the rights and privileges of a person? This includes: bandwidth staking, voting, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, all contracts have their own account, the same account a person would have.

If you want to deploy a contract for public consumption you would create an account for it, then deploy a contract onto it.